# unsupported SignatureMethod algorithm, but the algorithm is listed as available Service by BC-Provider

Tags: java, bouncycastle, xml-signature

to keep it short, my problem is as follows:

I add the BC-Provider at the beginning of my function:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

when i List all Services

```
BouncyCastleProvider().getServices();
```

the List contains
"RIPEMD160WITHECDSA"

on the last line of this codesnippet:

```
XMLSignatureFactory factory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext(pubkeys[i], sigElement);
valContext.setURIDereferencer(new FileDereferencer(
                              factory.getURIDereferencer(), new File("D:\\eclipseworkspace\\pathtoxml.xml")));
javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignature xmlSignature = factory.unmarshalXMLSignature(valContext);
```

i get an Exception with the Message:

unsupported SignatureMethod algorithm: http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-ripemd160

What does that mean? what is the difference between RIPEMD160WITHECDSA und the Algorithm specified by this URL?
Or is the url just not mapped to this Algorithmname?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
javax.xml.crypto.MarshalException: unsupported SignatureMethod algorithm: http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-ripemd160
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMSignatureMethod.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMSignedInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory.unmarshalXMLSignature(Unknown Source)
    at com.mobile.xmlsignature.XMLSigChecker.verify(XMLSigChecker.java:122)
    at com.mobile.xmlsignature.mainclass.main(mainclass.java:13)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [ecdsa-ripemd160](http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-ripemd160) is not one of the default signature methods registered with [DOMSignatureMethod](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/jcp/xml/dsig/internal/dom/DOMSignatureMethod.java.html).

According to [XMLSignatureFactory.newSignatureMethod()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/crypto/dsig/XMLSignatureFactory.html#newSignatureMethod%28java.lang.String,%20javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.SignatureMethodParameterSpec%29) you can probably register **ecdsa-ripemd160** using something like this:

```
xmlFact.newSignatureMethod(
    "http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-ripemd160", 
     MyECDSARipemd160Provider());
```

You will have to roll your own **MyECDSARipemd160Provider()** class to implement the [SignatureMethodParameterSpec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/crypto/dsig/spec/SignatureMethodParameterSpec.html) and it will need to identify your algorithm. I have not tried this and I suspect it might take some trial and error. I don't know if there is a BC class that does this for you. I would assume the [getAlgorithm()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/AlgorithmParameters.html#getAlgorithm%28%29) call to this class should return "RIPEMD160WITHECDSA".