# Unsupported Signature Method sha256-rsa-MGF1 for XML digital signature validation

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle, sha256, xml-signature

I'm doing XML digital signature validation, but the algorithm **SHA256WITHRSAANDMGF1** is not supported.

Here's the related part in XML file:

```xml
   <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"  Id="cXMLSignature">
      <ds:SignedInfo>
         <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
         <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#sha256-rsa-MGF1" />
         <ds:Reference URI="#cXMLSignedInfo">
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <ds:DigestValue>dafdfadfdfaddfadfefdafdfdfadfdaf=</ds:DigestValue>
         </ds:Reference>
      </ds:SignedInfo>
```

In the 4th line of the above xml, the signature method algorithm is:

```xml
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#sha256-rsa-MGF1" />
```

I tried something like below:

```java
        BouncyCastleProvider bc = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(bc);
        //...

        XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
        XMLSignature signature = fac.unmarshalXMLSignature(validateContext);
```

But got error:

```
 unsupported SignatureMethod algorithm: http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#sha256-rsa-MGF1
```

So I added a new line like below:

```java
fac.newSignatureMethod("http://www.w3.org/2007/05/xmldsig-more#sha256-rsa-MGF1", null);
```

But it also fails.

It seems that I need to implement the interface **SignatureMethodParameterSpec** for **SHA256WITHRSAANDMGF1** algorithm, but I'm not familiar with this implementation. Do you have any suggestions for this implementation? Or examples for it? Thanks!

This issue is also has the same problem: [unsupported SignatureMethod algorithm, but the algorithm is listed as available Service by BC-Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984025/unsupported-signaturemethod-algorithm-but-the-algorithm-is-listed-as-available)

Thanks!

---

---

**Update by myself**:

- This validation could be done by another library: https://santuario.apache.org/
- Here's the sample code:

```java
    // Configure for unsupported algorithm
    BouncyCastleProvider bc = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(bc);
    org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();

    // Load document
    File f = new File("C:/Archive/test.xml");
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/Archive/test.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(inputStream);

    // Public Key
    NodeList x509certNodeList = document.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "X509Certificate");
    String x509CertText = x509certNodeList.item(0).getTextContent();

    byte[] x509CertBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(x509CertText.getBytes());
    System.out.println("x509 Cert Text: " + x509CertText);

    CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(x509CertBytes));
    PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
    System.out.println("x509 Cert Public-Key Algorithm: " + publicKey.getAlgorithm());
    System.out.println("x509 Cert Public-Key Format: " + publicKey.getFormat());


    // Signature Value
    NodeList signValueNodeList = document.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "SignatureValue");
    String sigValue = signValueNodeList.item(0).getTextContent();
    System.out.println("SignatureValue: " + sigValue);


    // Validate
    NodeList signatureNodeList = document.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Signature");
    Node signatureNode = signatureNodeList.item(0);

    System.out.println("Signature Node Local Name: " + signatureNode.getLocalName());

    System.out.println("f: " + f.toURI().toURL().toString());

    org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature signature1 = new org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature(
            (Element)signatureNode, f.toURI().toURL().toString()
    );

    boolean result = signature1.checkSignatureValue(publicKey);
    System.out.println("result: " + result);
```